# Redirection of outbound UDP port

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, ntp

For my residential service, I changed ISPs to Zoom/Armstrong.  Just after that, my NTP daemons stopped working. I dug deep and diagnosed the problem:

Unprivileged ports are getting out.  When i run 'ntpdate' for example, I go out on a high, unprivleged port, and get a response on UDP 123.  That's fine.  The 'ntpd' daemon though, expects to go out on 123 and get its reply there as well.  This must be a common problem, because it's directly addressed in the [NTP troubleshooting guide](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/TroubleshootingNTP#Section_9.8.).

Just to see what would happen, I wrote a detailed email to the general support address at Armstrong. They replied almost immediately with a complete technical answer! They have everything <1024 blocked, except for a few ports to support outbound VPN.

So, the question:

Can I use IPtables to essentially re-write my outbound UDP 123 up to 2123 or something like that?  If I do, does there need to be a corresponding 2123->123 rule to translate the reply?  This seems like NAT, but with ports, not addresses. I tried, but can't seem to get iptables to do what I want.  I'm not sure if it's my lack of skill, or if I'm trying the wrong solution.

True, I could run ntpdate from cron, but that loses all of the adjustment smarts of NTP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule (untested):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --sport 123 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1025-65535
```

Comment: +1. Also, `-j SNAT --to local_ip:port` is possible here for non-dynamic IPs

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do that with the mangle table, but more normally why not use the state module?  I think this is kind of the standard iptables config that has the following rule:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere    anywhere     state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

This way holes will get punched in the firewall for return traffic...

Edit:
Oh, I missed that is your ISP blocking, well that is just a crap ISP, keeping this answer up in case it helps someone else who finds this question with a similar issue, but not your particular one.

Comment: The problem is that the link says that NTP counts on the replies going to 123, so any sort of nat/mangle rule on your end won't help because the ISP will block it before then.

Comment: I think it's just outbound.  ntpdate goes out high, comes back on 123 and works.  It's just my egress on 123 that seems to be blocked.